# GoogleAppsScriptをスプレッドシートにアドミンとして配置できません

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

【現状】
GoogleAppsScriptを「公開」-->「アドミンとして配置」-->「ウェブストアアイテムの下書きを更新」と選択してもエラーが表示されます。
添付のようにしっかり設定しているはずです。添付画像のようなエラーが表示されます。

【考えうる原因】
先日オーナーを変更したのでそれが何か影響しているのではと考えます。以前のオーナーがやったときはできたのですが、私をオーナーにしてやるとエラーがおきています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: エラー内容]

Answer (score 1):

オーナーを変更したということですが、Chrome Web Storeで公開するにはオーナー登録と登録料の支払いが必要だと思います。
この辺りは大丈夫でしょうか？